# Why is there no gem that uses the full shipping api for UPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I have a project I'm working on and they want to use UPS as a carrier for shipping, but all the gems that have anything to do with shipping only track and get rates, none of them use the shipping api to actually create shipments.  If anyone has found anything that does this I'd like to know.

Thanks in advance for everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you have a look at the shopify active_shipping gem?

https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping

Comment: Yeah, but they are the same way. Nothing for shipping, just tracking and rates.  I have forked their project though, I've started developing the shipping API for their gem, but just was hoping that someone else has developed something already.

Comment: They don't support UPS

Answer (score 2):

UPS appears to have requested that ActiveShipping cease using their API:
https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I believe that you will have to use UPS' API directly rather than using a gem.

EDIT

You may use EasyPost as a solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/transcriptic/ups-shipping is the best I've found.

It's got some bugs, hopefully I'll get them fixed soon.

Comment: I've since developed my own gem for this, which also includes FedEx and soon USPS.  If you want to look at my [gem](https://github.com/Digi-Cazter/omniship) and if you have any suggestions or want to contribute, that would be great. Thanks for the resource though, I'll be sure to look at it.